# ECSchnorr Still getting wrong (hash?) results

Tags: java, signing, elliptic-curve

I'm writing Schnorr signature algorithm on elliptic curves. I get instructions from [here (page 128)](https://books.google.pl/books?id=J3ERJHJ_QuEC&pg=PA129&lpg=PA129&dq=ec+schnorr+sign&source=bl&ots=_SkRL1-jnk&sig=r6yD0RJ_ymJFfIBtlM7ngGn2IKQ&hl=pl&sa=X&ved=0CFAQ6AEwBWoVChMI5cGL3-XtyAIVRVYUCh0PUw6V#v=onepage&q&f=false)

Here's my code

```
Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());

    //key generation
    ECParameterSpec ecSpec = ECNamedCurveTable.getParameterSpec("prime192v1");
    ECPoint G = ecSpec.getG();
    BigInteger order = ecSpec.getN();

    BigInteger x = BigIntegers.createRandomInRange(BigInteger.ONE, order.subtract(BigInteger.ONE), new SecureRandom());
    ECPoint Y = G.multiply(x);

    //sign
    BigInteger r = BigIntegers.createRandomInRange(BigInteger.ONE, order.subtract(BigInteger.ONE), new SecureRandom());
    ECPoint R = G.multiply(r);

    byte[] xArray = R.getXCoord().getEncoded();
    byte[] yArray = R.getYCoord().getEncoded();

    String xBinary;
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i = 0; i < xArray.length; i++){
        sb.append(String.format("%8s", Integer.toBinaryString(xArray[i] & 0xFF)).replace(' ', '0'));
    }
    xBinary = sb.toString();

    sb = new StringBuilder();
    String yBinary;
    for(int i = 0; i < yArray.length; i++){
        sb.append(String.format("%8s", Integer.toBinaryString(yArray[i] & 0xFF)).replace(' ', '0'));
    }
    yBinary = sb.toString();

    int hash = (xBinary + yBinary + "msg").hashCode();
    BigInteger h = BigInteger.valueOf(hash);

    BigInteger s = r.add(h.multiply(x)).mod(order);

    //verify    
    ECPoint tmp1 = G.multiply(s);
    ECPoint tmp2 = Y.multiply(h);
    ECPoint R2 = tmp1.subtract(tmp2);

    xArray = R2.getXCoord().getEncoded();
    yArray = R2.getYCoord().getEncoded();

    sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i = 0; i < xArray.length; i++){
        sb.append(String.format("%8s", Integer.toBinaryString(xArray[i] & 0xFF)).replace(' ', '0'));
    }
    xBinary = sb.toString();

    sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i = 0; i < yArray.length; i++){
        sb.append(String.format("%8s", Integer.toBinaryString(yArray[i] & 0xFF)).replace(' ', '0'));
    }
    yBinary = sb.toString();

    int hash2 = (xBinary + yBinary + "msg").hashCode();
    BigInteger h2 = BigInteger.valueOf(hash2);
```

But I'm still getting wrong results (hashes don't match) and I don't see why. Am I taking wrong parameters at the beginnig or using wrong methods to make calculations on points
Any help would be appreciated

**EDIT**

It started working after I changed

```
ECPoint Y = G.multiply(x);
(...)
ECPoint R = G.multiply(r);
(...)
ECPoint R2 = tmp1.subtract(tmp2);
```

to

```
ECPoint Y = G.multiply(x).normalize();
(...)
ECPoint R = G.multiply(r).normalize();
(...)
ECPoint R2 = tmp1.subtract(tmp2).normalize();
```